# Backbone routing doesn't work when converted to TypeScript

Tags: backbone.js, typescript, backbone-routing

I'm trying to convert a basic Backbone.js router declaration to TypeScript.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "*actions": "defaultRoute"
    },

    defaultRoute: function () {
        document.write("Default Route Invoked");
    }
});

var app_router = new AppRouter();

Backbone.history.start();
```

My converted code is the following which doesn't work:

```
class AppRouter extends Backbone.Router {
    routes = {
        "*actions": "defaultRoute"
    }

    defaultRoute() {
        document.write("Default Route Invoked");
    }
}

var app_router = new AppRouter();

Backbone.history.start();
```

I get no compile time or runtime errors but the code does not function. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all initialized fields in the constructor and make a call to `super` at the end:

```
class AppRouter extends Backbone.Router {

    routes: any;
    constructor(options?: Backbone.RouterOptions) {

        this.routes = {
            "*actions": "defaultRoute"
        }

        super(options);
    }

    initialize() {
        // can put more init code here to run after constructor
    }

    defaultRoute() {
        document.write("Default Route Invoked");
    }
}

var app_router = new AppRouter();

Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: I get this error. A 'super' call must be the first statement in the constructor when a class contains initialized properties or has parameter properties.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a look at `Backbone.Router.extends` and it isn't a basic prototype extension - so you can't just switch from `Backbone.Router.extends` to a TypeScript class extension.

I would change your TypeScript file to look more like your original JavaScript - you'll still get the benefit of intellisense and type checking - you just aren't using a class:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "*actions": "defaultRoute"
    },

    defaultRoute: function () {
        document.write("Default Route Invoked");
    }
});

var app_router = new AppRouter();

Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Backbone [source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-193) shows that the extend method is the same for all backbone types.
`Model.extend = Collection.extend = Router.extend = View.extend = History.extend = extend;` where do you see difference in the router's prototype extension?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting the Backbone ones are different to each other - they are different to the one generated by TypeScript when you use inheritance. You can use `var app_router: Backbone.Router = ...` but TypeScript will probably already type app_router without making it explicit.

Comment: I expanded this question a little more in [this other Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632714/converting-backbone-structures-to-typescript).

Comment: @orad I answered your question. [Take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632714/converting-backbone-structures-to-typescript/14657969#14657969)

Answer (score 2):

As Steve Fenton mentioned it's because Typescripts extend does not work in the same way as underscore / backones extend method.

The main problem is that the router calls *_bindRoutes()* before your *routes* field has been set in the "sub class" in type scripts hierachy.

A call to *Backbone.Router.apply(this, arguments)* in the constructor of your ts class as described by orad, ensures that this call will be made after the *routes* field has been set.

A manual call to this function will do the trick as well.

and just a FYI: call *delegateEvents(this.events)* in the constructor of your view classes if you want the dom events from your element to get triggered

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to work with typescript 3.x . The `super()` method should be called before using `this`. Reordering code won't work because backbone is initializing routes within the `super()` method. Here is a version where the route configuration is directly passed to `super()`.

```js
class AppRouter extends Backbone.Router {

    constructor() {

        super({
            routes: {
                "*actions": "defaultRoute"
            }
        });
    }
}
```