# Converting Backbone structures to TypeScript

Tags: backbone.js, typescript

Looking at Backbonejs' implementation of the [extend function](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-186), it shows that it isn't a basic prototype extension, and when backbone extensions are converted straight to TypeScript classes some things stop functioning. What is the right way to convert each component of Backbonejs (Model, Collection, Route, View, History) to a typescript class and make sure nothing is broken?

Thanks!

**Update:**
The answer in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14699633/450913) can also work for other backbone constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the code generated by TypeScript first calls the Router constructor and then declares the routes.

*Code generated by TypeScript compiler*

```
...
function AppRouter() {
    _super.apply(this, arguments);

    this.routes = { // <= routes defined after _super constructor
        "*actions": "defaultRoute"
    };
}
...
```

To fix this just call the Backbone Router function `_bindRoutes()` on your TypeScript object constructor.

Example:

```
class AppRouter extends Backbone.Router {
    routes = {
        "*actions": "defaultRoute"
    }

    constructor(){
        super();
        // call _bindRoutes() here function to bind your routes
        (<any>this)._bindRoutes();
    }

    defaultRoute() {
        document.write("Default Route Invoked");
    }
}

var app_router = new AppRouter();

Backbone.history.start();
```

Download a sample code [here](https://github.com/Diullei/ts-backbone)

Comment: Thanks, but how about the rest of backbone constructs? I have this problem with Models, Views, Collections, etc. It looks like the workaround is different for each one.

Comment: if you give me an example of each error I can help you to solve :)

Comment: With your hint I figured for each of these constructs if I call the constructor of the extended backbone class from the constructor of the inheriting TypeScript class then that would fix it. For example: ```constructor(options?: Backbone.RouterOptions) {
            super(options);
            Backbone.Router.apply(this, arguments);
        }```

Comment: I'm happy to have helped! :)